# Sencha Touch 1.1 Lists, Store, "animating" store updates in the view (fade/blink in)

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

When I update the store using storeObj.insert(modelObj) the List-panel updates itself, as it should. However, Id like to see the newly added item "animate" when it appears in the view. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model, have an extra field called newItem. So your model will be:

```
Ext.regModel('Product', {
    fields: [
        **{name: 'newItem',     type: 'boolean'},**
        {name: 'name',        type: 'string'},
        {name: 'description', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'price',       type: 'float'},
        {name: 'image_url',   type: 'string'},
        {name: 'in_stock',    type: 'boolean'}
    ]
});
```

When you insert item into store with

```
storeObj.insert(modelObj)
```

you must have **modelObj.newItem=true** before inserting.

Also, before inserting any new item in, you have to mark all the old items as "NOT NEW". For that you may have to use a dummystore.

Now use EXt.xTemplate like following: (for your Ext.List)

```
itemTpl: '<tpl for=".">' 
    + '<tpl if="newItem==1">' 
    + '    <p color="red"> this item is new</p></tpl>' 
    + '<tpl else >
    + '    this item is old</tpl>' 
    + '</tpl>',
```

Comment: Follow-up question: Ive never done a dummystore before, how would that work?

Comment: there is nothing like dummystore....by dummy store I meant use a temporary store to copy original store and mark all its model instances as not new...then put all these "not new" instances back in original store along with those which are inserted later having newItem value as 1. How did you try itemTpl....did that work?